Difference between place, valuation, prime, and absolute value
In algebraic geometry/number theory, I keep seeing authors use the words prime, place, valuation, and absolute value seemingly interchangeably.
In Neukirch’s book, he appears to use valuation to mean absolute value even though I know these are different things.
Question: is there a standard definition for each of these things and how are they related? (Place, prime, valuation, absolute value)
(I know you can get absolute values from valuations and vice verse, so I assume this is why they use these two interchangeably)

A prime is a prime element in a ring, so that is clear, I believe (for $p\mid ab$, either $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$). For "place" see this post. There is a standard definition for valuation as well, see wikipedia. As you suspected, it includes an absolute value as a special case in the multiplicative version.

Dietrich Burde answered most of the question in his comment, so I will simply explain the relation between these concepts.
For simplicity, we take a number field $K$, although the story is very similar for other fields. I'm sure you've heard some of this story before, but let me summarise it.
If the number ring $\mathcal{O}_K$ of $K$ is a UFD, then picking a prime element $p\in \mathcal{O}_K$ gives rise to a valuation on $\mathcal{O}_K$, simply by $\nu_p(\alpha) = e$ where $e$ is the maximal integer such that $p^e$ divides $\alpha$. If it is not UFD, a better way is to use prime ideals - when authors refer to primes, they may either refer to prime elements or prime ideals, depending on the context. The idea is the same, for $\mathfrak{p}\subset \mathcal{O}_K$ a prime ideal, we define $\nu_\mathfrak{p}(\alpha) = e$ where $e$ is the maximal integer such that $\langle \alpha\rangle \subset \mathfrak{p}^e$. This works well because of unique factorisation of ideals in Dedekind domains.
Now, every such valuation gives rise to an absolute value, namely by $|\alpha|_\mathfrak{p}:=p^{-\nu_\mathfrak{p}(\alpha)}$, with $p$ being the prime of $\Bbb{Z}$ below $\mathfrak{p}$. Furthermore, all of this extends to $K$ very naturally.
One can check that the properties of the valuation means that the induced absolute value is an ultra-metric. These are non-archimedean absolute values of $K$. For every embedding of $K$ in $\Bbb{R}$, and every pair of embeddings in $\Bbb{C}$, you furthermore induce absolute values on $K$ coming from the standard absolute value on $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{C}$ respectively. These are archimedean absolute values on $K$.
Ostrowski's theorem tells us that up to equivalence, these are all the non-trivial absolute values on $K$, and so we call such an equivalence class a place of $K$.
